# jQuery | JJ Carousel Plugin - Can’t set speed

Tags: plugins, jquery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I am trying to use NextGen Gallery with the JJ Carousel plugin. The scrolling works now, but I can’t setup the speed of the carousel. JJ wrote:

> animation: The speed of the scroll animation as string in jQuery terms ("slow" or "fast") or milliseconds as integer (See jQuery Documentation). If set to 0, animation is turned off. (sc: animation="setting")

But anything I set in there will not work, no difference between 'fast' and '5000'.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jj-nextgen-jquery-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

#### The animation speed only applies if your adding an animation.

The scrolling carousel is not considered an animation.  You would have to enable easing for the animation to take effect.

You can view an example of the easing with the speed declaration on the j[Carousel jQuery plugin page.](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_easing.html)

jCarousel does not contain any built in easing functions.  You would have to include the jQuery Easing plugin or use an inline easing equation like [Robert Penner's Easing Equations:](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/easing_demo.html)

```
Query.easing['BounceEaseOut'] = function(p, t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
    } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
    } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
    } else {
        return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
    }
};
```

To use the above with jCarousel:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        easing: 'BounceEaseOut',
        animation: 1000
    });
});
```